# Why is data set with Meteor Iron Router not available in the template rendered callback?

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

This is a bit puzzling to me.  I set data in the router (which I'm using very simply intentionally at this stage of my project), as follows :

```
Router.route('/groups/:_id',function() {
    this.render('groupPage', {
        data : function() {
            return Groups.findOne({_id : this.params._id});
        }
    }, { sort : {time: -1} } );
});
```

The data you would expect, is now available in the template helpers, but if I have a look at 'this' in the rendered function its `null`

```
Template.groupPage.rendered = function() {
    console.log(this);
};
```

I'd love to understand why (presuming its an expected result), or If its something I'm doing / not doing that causes this?

Comment: To get the data you should call `console.log(this.data());` ?

Comment: yeah, thanks - i was just inspecting the whole object, but despite whether i log this or this.data, this.data is still equal to null, which is really the crux of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, this isn't uncommon.  Below is how I handle it in my routes.

From what I understand, the template gets rendered client-side while the client is subscribing, so the `null` is actually what data is available.

Once the client recieves data from the subscription (server), it is added to the collection which causes the template to re-render.

Below is the pattern I use for routes.  Notice the `if(!this.ready()) return;`
 which handles the no data situation.

```
Router.route('landing', {
  path: '/b/:b/:brandId/:template',
  onAfterAction: function() {
    if (this.title) document.title = this.title;
  },
  data: function() {
    if(!this.ready()) return;
    var brand = Brands.findOne(this.params.brandId);
    if (!brand) return false;
    this.title = brand.title;
    return brand;
  },
  waitOn: function() {
    return [
      Meteor.subscribe('landingPageByBrandId', this.params.brandId),
      Meteor.subscribe('myProfile'),  // For verification
    ];
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

### Issue

I was experiencing this myself today.  I believe that there is a race condition between the Template.rendered callback and the iron router data function.  [I have since raised a question as an IronRouter issue on github](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/1283) to deal with the core issue.

### In the meantime, workarounds:

#### Option 1: Wrap your code in a window.setTimeout()

```
Template.groupPage.rendered = function() {
    var data_context = this.data;
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(data_context);
    }, 100);
};
```

#### Option 2: Wrap your code in a this.autorun()

```
Template.groupPage.rendered = function() {
    var data_context = this.data;
    this.autorun(function() {
        console.log(data_context);
    });
};
```

Note: in this option, the function will run every time that the template's data context changes!  The autorun will be destroyed along with the template though, unlike `Tracker.autorun` calls.